# Incorporate duplicates in a list of tuples into a dictionary summing the values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, counter

Hi I wish to convert this list of tuples into dictionary. As I am new to python, I am figuring out ways to convert into dictionary. I could only convert into dictionary if there is only one value. In my case, there are two values in it.I will demonstrate with more details below:

```
    `List of tuples: [('Samsung', 'Handphone',10), ('Samsung', 'Handphone',-1),
('Samsung','Tablet',10),('Sony','Handphone',100)]`
```

As you can see above, I wish to identify 'Samsung' as the key and 'Handphone' and '10' as the values with respect to the key.

My desired output would be:

```
  `Output: {'Sony': ['Handphone',100], 'Samsung': ['Tablet',10,'Handphone', 9]}`
```

As you can see above, the item 'handphone' and 'tablet' are group according to the key values which in my case is Sony and Samsung. The quantity of the item are are added / subtracted if they belong to the same item and same key (Samsung or Sony).

I would really appreciate any suggestions and ideas that you guys have in order to achieve the above output. I really ran out of ideas. Thank you.

Comment: `Samsung` appears multiple times in your list.  A dictionary can only have one instance of a key.  What should happen for the multiple entries with the same key?

Comment: I would suggest a dictionary of dictionaries instead of the (invalid) output format you requested.
The result in this format: {'Sony': {'Handphone': 100}, 'Samsung': {'Handphone': 9, 'Tablet': 10}}

Comment: Hi @John1024, pardon me. Can I ask why my desired output is not a valid dictionary?

Comment: Hi @BrendanAbel, for the multiple entries with the same key, it will remove duplicate item, which in my case is handphone and it sum the quantity of the handphone respectively.

Comment: Hi @Wehrdo, in my case, how should i go about doing dictionary of dictionaries? Pardon me. As I am still new to python. Thank you.

Comment: @user3271404 See the top-rated answer on how to make the dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: Hi @Wehrdo, Sorry for my ignorance. Thanks for explaining the error in my question. I have edited my "desired output" as shown above. Thank you.

Comment: @user3271404 Very good.  The new desired output works.

Comment: @user3271404 Your desired output is now syntactically correct, but it is a difficult output to create, and does not represent the idea well. The answers by Josha and Seiji show a representation using nested dictionaries that intuitively captures what you're trying to represent.

The new desired output requires interpreting elements at even indices as "object types", and the succeeding element as its count. e.g, index 2 is the key "Handphone", and index 3 is the number of handphones. While this is technically feasible, it is a misuse of lists. (continued...)

Comment: (cont.) Besides adding complexity, this data structure will have poor performance on large datasets. It requires you to search through the entire list of item types to find what you're looking for. If you have 1000 item types for a manufacturer, on average you will have to search through 1000 elements to find where the count is stored.

Comment: Backticks aren't necessary in code blocks

Comment: @Wehrdo, Hi, thank for your further insights. I will take note that code is not feasible to big datasets. I will try discuss with my group mates how should I improve efficiency of the code. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good opportunity for `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

the_list = [
    ('Samsung', 'Handphone', 10), 
    ('Samsung', 'Handphone', -1), 
    ('Samsung', 'Tablet', 10),
    ('Sony', 'Handphone', 100)
]

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for brand, thing, quantity in the_list:
    d[brand][thing] += quantity
```

Result will be

```
{
    'Samsung': {
        'Handphone': 9, 
        'Tablet': 10
    },
    'Sony': {
        'Handphone': 100
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Josha Inglis, how to produce the result above? I have tried but I could not. Pardon me. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @user3271404 you should be able to copy/paste the answer above, then `print(d)` to see the dictionary.

Comment: To access `'Samsung'` `'Handphone'`, you can use `d['Samsung']['Handphone']`

Comment: Roger, thank you so much additional information. However, when i try to print d, it shows `defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x02845C70>, {'Sony': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'Handphone': 100})`, any idea how to remove this? Thank you!

Comment: Roger, thank you so much additional information. However, when i try to print d, it shows `defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x02845C70>, {'Sony': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'Handphone': 100})`, any idea how to remove "defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x02845C70>"? Thank you!

Comment: would require your help to answer my question above. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Josha Inglis, I would require your help to answer my question above. Thank you.

Comment: Inglish, I have been trying to figure out your code. However, I could not understand it. How does this `d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))` works? Thank you!

Comment: I have been trying to figure out your code. However, I could not understand it. How does this d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)) works? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a dictionary comprehension

What you really want are *tuples* for keys, which will be the company and the device.

```
tuples = [('Samsung', 'Handphone',10), 
          ('Samsung', 'Handphone',-1),
          ('Samsung','Tablet',10),
          ('Sony','Handphone',100)]

d = {}
for company, device, n in tuples:
    key = (company, device)
    d[key] = d.get(key, 0) + n
```

Comment: This does not do the addition of matching "Samsung Handphone" items. Each new Samsung item will just overwrite the previous one.

Comment: @Wehrdo Ah, it wasn't really clear from the question that was what they wanted.

Comment: Hi @Wehrdo, sorry for ambiguity in the question. I am trying to as clear as I could. What do u suggest to make my question clearer? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your output has a problem, that can be seen with proper identation:

```
{
    'Sony': ['Handphone',100], 
    'Samsung': ['Tablet',10],
    ['Handphone', 9]
}
```

Handphone isn't a part of 'Samsung', you can do a list of lists to get:

```
{
    'Sony': [
        ['Handphone',100]
    ],
    'Samsung': [
        ['Tablet',10],
        ['Handphone', 9]
    ]
}
```

With:

```
my_list = [('Samsung', 'Handphone',10), ('Samsung', 'Handphone',-1), ('Samsung','Tablet',10),('Sony','Handphone',100)]

result = {}
for brand, device, value in my_list:
    # first verify if key is present to add list for the first time
    if not brand in result:
        result[brand] = []
    # then add new list to already existent list
    result[brand] += [[device, value]]
```

But I think the best format would be a dict:

```
{
    'Sony': {
        'Handphone': 100
    },
    'Samsung': {
        'Tablet': 10,
        'Handphone': 9
    }
}
```

That would be like:

```
my_list = [('Samsung', 'Handphone',10), ('Samsung', 'Handphone',-1), ('Samsung','Tablet',10),('Sony','Handphone',100)]

result = {}
for brand, device, value in my_list:
    # first verify if key is present to add dict for the first time
    if not brand in result:
        result[brand] = {}
    # then add new key/value to already existent dict
    result[brand][device] = value
```

Comment: Hi @Seiji Hirao, how to produce the result? I could not get it. Pardon me. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, my python has some issues just now. I could print the output already. Thank for your clear and concise explanation. I have understood how it works. Brilliant! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad it helped ;)